# ¿Como realizar sentencia if con JSTL Java? [Java EE]

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa, if, jstl

estoy intentando listar operadores cuyo nivel o tipo de usuario es igual a 3.

Claramente tengo un error en la sintaxis o en la comparación que hago. Espero puedan ayudar.

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${listPostulant}" var="postulant">
        <c:if test="${postulant.getLevelUser()== "3"}">
            <tr>
                <td>${postulant.getIdUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getNameUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getLastnameUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getRunUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getUsernameUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getPasswordUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getCellphoneUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getStatus()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getLevelUser()}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

CAPTURA:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quedo atento a sus respuestas.

Comment: Por favor, pon el código relevante como texto, no como pantallazos, para ayudar a la gente que te puede ayudar.

Comment: No pongas capturas, pon el código como texto. ¿Has probado con `${postulant.levelUser eq '3'}`?

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la forma que dice Pablo.

El código correctamente funcional es el siguiente:

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${listPostulant}" var="postulant">
        <c:if test="${postulant.getLevelUser() eq '3'}">
            <tr>
                <td>${postulant.getIdUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getNameUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getLastnameUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getRunUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getUsernameUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getPasswordUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getCellphoneUser()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getStatus()}</td>
                <td>${postulant.getLevelUser()}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:if>
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Muchas gracias.